# Are there sources explaining sleep talking/walking?

Tags: sleep

I have heard of interpreting symbols, things or people who appear in a dream like Eliyahu. I have also - in regards to sleep - heard of Rabbonim who could recite or review Torah in their sleep. In a shiur, I learned that in inquiring of the future, drunks and (sleeping) children can provide insight, though not something to rely on. But are there sources explaining sleep talking/walking?

The question is of particular interest because I have sometimes "severe" (aka hilarious) episodes of sleep talking or walking.

Comment: intriguing question but not sure what you mean by spiritual sources.

Comment: @Dude because I'm not looking for halachic insights. I was trying to avoid saying kabbalistic incase there were answers outside that realm.

Comment: it's a strange phrasing and why limit the sources that may or may not talk about this? Also just b/c something is in nigle doesn't mean it is halachic